# WebStorm + React-Native : Navigator is deprecated and has been removed from this package

Tags: android, ios, node.js, react-native, webstorm

I am going through the react-native tutorials on lynda.com, "React-Native: Building Mobile Apps". The difference lies in the fact that I am using WebStorm to develop JavaScript based apps. I've created the files according to the tutorial:

appContainer.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Drawer, View } from "react-native";
import { Navigator } from "react-native";

export default class AppContainer extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            store: {},
            toggled: false,
            theme: null
        }
    }
    toggleDrawer(){
        this.state.toggled ? this._drawer.close() : this._drawer.open();
    }
    openDrawer(){
        this.setState({toggled: true});
    }
    closeDrawer(){
        this.setState({toggled: false});
    }
    renderScene(route, navigator){
        switch(route){
            default: {
                return null
            }
        }
    }
    configureScene(route, routeStack){
        return Navigator.SceneConfigs.PushFromRight;
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <Drawer
                ref={(ref) => this._drawer = ref}
                type="displace"
                content={<View style={{backgroundColor: "#000", height: 1000}}
                />}
                onClose={this.closeDrawer.bind(this)}
                onOpen={this.openDrawer.bind(this)}
                openDrawerOffset={0.2}
                >
                <Navigator
                    ref={(ref) => this._navigator = ref}
                    configureScene={this.configureScene.bind(this)}
                    renderScene={this.renderScene.bind(this)}
                />
            </Drawer>
        );
    }
}
```

index.ios.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry
} from 'react-native';

import AppContainer from "./app/appContainer";

export default class dinder extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <AppContainer/>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('dinder', () => dinder);
```

Run/Debug Configuration screen:

[image]

However, when I run the app by selecting run 'ios' from the run drop down windows, I am receiving the following error in the emulator window:

[image]

Can someone please explain how I can fix this issue within the confines of the code presented for the tutorial that I pasted?

Comment: Navigator is indeed deprecated. I would recommend you find a newer tutorial and start using some of the new navigation libraries. Something like this https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In React-Nav 0.44.3 the Navigator has been deprecated: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.44.3, so is not really a webstorm's configuration's issue.

To fix this, you can follow this [Github issue](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/1328), install the **react-native-deprecated-custom-components** package through npm or yarn.

And then in your appContainer.js, replace your

`import { Navigator } from "react-native";`

with

`import NavigationExperimental from 'react-native-deprecated-custom-components';`

And change all your `Navigator` call to `NavigationExperimenal.Navigator`